# Software manager and update issue

Tags: software-installation, update-manager

I am having a little trouble getting my update manager to refresh. There is an error message (`'$ept2nd2006' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eduke32.list`):

```
E:The list of sources could not be read. 
Go to the repository dialog to correct the problem.
E:_cache->open() failed, please report.
```

When I try to open the GDebi package installer I get a error:

> Software index is broken"(This is a major failure of your software
>   management system. Please check for broken packages with Synaptic
>   Package Manager, check the file permissions and correctness of the
>   file 'etc/apt/sources.list' and reload the software information
>   with:'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get install -f'

I got the same error message when I opened `SPM` and it closed automatically.

For a brief history of what I initially did. I was following the command script to install eduke32 via the [this tutorial](http://mintguide.org/games/action/121-duke-nukem-3d-shooter-from-the-first-person.html) in the first line of command script, where the long vertical line is, I pressed enter a finished the line of script and then entered my password.

How do I correct this problem?

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: I have googled all I could and I am obviously very new to Linux. I really like it and hope I can get this issue resolved. I am not sure how to format my question or rephrase it any better. I just really need some help. Any information or assistance anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AdamMitchell I just did it for you, A.B. was referring to using the code formatting buttons in the editor when you post your question to set apart the error messages from the rest of the text. Also, try putting spaces in between lines, it makes it easier to read. His comment was a bit brusque, since you're new to Ask Ubuntu and thus couldn't be expected to know how to use the editor totally properly.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get update`, and then `sudo apt-get install -f` like it suggests?

Comment: Yes I have and nothing is different. I am just assuming that when I entered my password out of context according to the line of script, terminal though it was a command and tried to execute it. In order to fix this problem I think I have to find the file that was created by the terminal and delete it. Problem is, I don't know where to find it.

Comment: Also, thanks RPi Awesomeness for the clarification. I appreciate the assistance. Also something I just realized. Getting the updates through the terminal would also requires a working internet connection. I don't really have that at the moment. I am using data on my smart phone to try to figure this out. Once I know what I need to do I can get the laptop to leach off the LTE connection from my phone.

Comment: I am still trying to get this issue resolved. If anyone has any ideas on what I can do, your help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks to those who assisted by reformatting my question. All I need now is the answer.